# "Transcode" copying video/audio codec

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, h.264, transcode, image-stabilization

I took some very shaky video, and went online to try and find how to stabilize it. I came upon [this nice blog](http://blog.hamoid.com/stabilize-video-in-ubuntu-linux) that uses [transcode](https://bitbucket.org/france/transcode-tcforge/downloads) for it.
Following the blog instructions it worked very nice, but the end result had a lot of compression artifacts. This I imagine is mostly due to using xvid as a new codec.

My intention is reuse the codec the camera originally used which is H.264/AVC but I haven't found a way of doing so (ran into various dead ends using either encoder -y mov... or -y ffpmeg.

In particular when using -y ffmpeg -F "-vcodec copy -acodec copy" it prints out:

```
[export_ffmpeg.so] warning: Video template standard must be one of pal/ntsc
```

but running

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mov
```

Presents no problem.

Any idea on how to do this? or an alternative to stabilize video on linux?.

Comment: FFmpeg comes with a [deshake filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#deshake), but I've never used it so I don't know how effective it is.

Comment: Thanks [LordNeckbeard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1109017/lordneckbeard). I had not thought of using deshake as a keyword. I see this filter was implemented only 9 months ago, so I'll have to go get the new version (and couldn't find any examples online) but I'm optimistic about it.